# Take the last primary key id enter in the database to var

Tags: php, sql, key, var

I need to select the last `id` I entered in the database and put it in a var. I create my var in PHP:

```
$timId = "" ;
```

but I tried something like this:

```
$requete = $bdd->prepare('SELECT LAST(`timId`)  FROM `timesheets`   ');
$requete->execute(array('timId'=> $_POST['timId'])) or die(print_r($requete->errorInfo()));
$resultat = $requete->fetch();
$timId = $resultat['timId'];
echo($timId);
```

I know my syntax of SQL is wrong but how I do it?

Comment: you want to use a 'order by id desc' if id is auto increment and primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use Order BY id Desc , Using limit clause you can achieve this
```

Comment: Thanks here the correct syntax : SELECT  `timId` 
FROM  `timesheets` 
ORDER BY  `timId` Desc
LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Usually if using mysql, you should use "select last_insert_id()"

That assumes you're using an auto_increment column, of course.

Also, depending on the class of $bdd, it might have a method to get the last inserted id anyway.

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin to try my request in my database.